# Google App Engine - How can I improve my cold start JVM time?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm not new to improving my cold start time, I've spent many hours trying different things.  I'd like if possible to know **exactly** what the Google App Engine does during a cold start.

I have a log statement as described here http://code.google.com/intl/nl/appengine/kb/java.html#performance to show when my code first gets control.

I have two apps that I have been testing, one is simple, and my code first gets control after about 1 second.

The other one has lots of files and stuff and my code first gets control after about 2 seconds.  This one doesn't use any more libraries than the other one, however it does have a lot more jsps and java classes.

Could simply having more java and jsp classes cause slower cold start, even if the class isn't used?